# Java LinkedLists in LinkedLists - Access items

Tags: java, linked-list

I have at least for me a tricky thing for university to do.
I have to create a LinkedList in where other LinkedLists are saved.

In these Linkedlists are text patterns saved, I want to change them with specific commands. However, I have no clue how to access these LinkedListes. If I use .get, I receive only the saved LinkedList as an object. I found no way to read the items that are saved within this object or so earlier LinkedList.

```
LinkedList listrows = new LinkedList();
LinkedList listcolumn1 = new LinkedList();
LinkedList listcolumn2 = new LinkedList();

listcolumn1.add("test");
listcolumn1.add("test");
listcolumn2.add("hello");
listcolumn2.add("hello");

listrows.add(listcolumn1);
listrows.add(listcolumn2);

//here is my problem now, I cannot save it as a LinkedList
//because linkedlist is giving back an object
LinkedList listedit= new LinkedList();
listedit=listrows.get(0) //<-error

//If I use syso, only the object name is printed
System.out.println(listrows.get(0)) //Printed e.g.: [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should read the articles given at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info especially the one about generics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the exact types you need :

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> listrows = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> listcolumn1 = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> listcolumn2 = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then:

```
LinkedList<String> listedit = listrows.get(0);
```

Your problem was that you used the raw `LinkedList` type, so `listrows.get(0)` returned an instance of `Object` type instead of the internal `LinkedList`.

Comment: Thank you... was really struggling with it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this according to generic programming concept,

```
  LinkedList<String> lt1=new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> lt2=new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList< LinkedList<String>> lt=new LinkedList< LinkedList<String>>();

        lt1.add("One");
        lt1.add("Two");
        lt1.add("Three");

        lt2.add("A");
        lt2.add("B");
        lt2.add("C");

        lt.add(lt1);
        lt.add(lt2);

        System.out.println(""+lt.get(0));
```